# How to get different response from a single $http call with different url in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two different url in my app. I just want to get two different response and want to assign it to two different objects. Here is the code below.

```
> angular.module('App',[]).controller('Ctr',function($scope,http){
>         var urls = {
>               "data11":"data1.json",
>               "data22":"data2.json"
>         };
>         for(var val in urls){
>           console.log(urls[val]);
>           http.getData(urls[val]).then(function(resp){
>             $scope[val] = resp;
>           });
>         }
>         console.log($scope);
>             
>       }).factory('http',function($http){
>             return{
>               getData:function(url){
>                 console.log("url",url);
>                 return $http.get(url).then(function(resp){
>                   return resp;
>                 });
>               }
>             }
>       });
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aMPVaAtQfINq8SywxvZt?p=preview)

Comment: Make your API return all the data in one request that is better if you are requesting data from same server. So your response will look like Ex: `{ users: [], categories: [] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, when your http callbacks are executed, `val` is `undefined` as your loop is already finished. You need to preserve the `val` in http call's block by creating new scope for the `val`. For example you can use closure:

```
for(var val in urls) {
   (function() { 
     var newVal = val;
     http.getData(urls[newVal]).then(function(resp){
       $scope[newVal] = resp;
     });
   })();
 }
```